# How to assign a number of properties to an existing object IF that property also has nested properties inside of it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My data contains an empty object which I would like to populate with properties. Currently it looks like this:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        chartData: {}
    }
},
```

Essentially, I want to create this structure:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        chartData: {
            labels: ["One", "Two"];
            datasets: [{
                data: ["5", "10"],
                label: "Chart"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

This like of code successfully adds the labels property and value whilst keeping reactivity, however, I can't figure out how to also add the datasets property which has nested properties itself

```
this.chartData = Object.assign({}, this.chartData, { labels: ['One', 'Two']})
```

I figured this one out by reading https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html , however, they haven't shown how to add properties which have nested properties.

Comment: The first piece of code is my Vue.js data which has an empty chartData object. The second piece of code is the object I want to create programmatically without hard coding it and the third piece of code is how I add the first property to the empty charData object. What do you mean by "Where's the extra data coming from?"

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method of building that object using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
// Empty chartData
const chartData = {};

// Your two sets of data
const labels = ['One', 'Two'];
const datasets = { datasets: [{ data: ['5', '10'], label: 'Chart'}] };

// Merge the existing chartData, and labels and datasets together
const newChartData = { chartData: { ...chartData, labels: [...labels], ...datasets } };

console.log(newChartData);
```

Comment: I'm gonna try what you've suggested, however, I believe this will not make the object reactive.

Comment: I've updated it so that `labels` is copied rather than referenced.